# counting the number of strings from text files

Tags: awk

I have a text file with 10 columns say f.txt which looks like below:

```
aab abb  263-455
aab abb  263-455
aab abb  263-455
bbb abb  26-455
bbb abb  26-455
bbb aka  264-266
bga bga  230-232
bga bga  230-232
```

I want to count the unique number of each string in the first and second columns based on the numbers of third column.

Output:

```
aab - 1
abb - 2
bbb - 2
aka - 1
bga - 2

Total no - 8
```

Comment: Shouldn't the count for `bga` be 1?

Comment: So what's the question? You want someone to implement it for you? And I don't understand what the numbers in the third column are used for. And you say there are 10 columns in the file?

Comment: @sudo It should be 2. The number of bga in the first column is one. In the second column also one number. so total is two.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear, check out my answer, should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
       !s[1":"$1":"$3]++{sU[$1]++;tot++} 
       !s[2":"$2":"$3]++{sU[$2]++;tot++} 
       END{
         for (x in sU) print x, sU[x]; 
         print "Total No -",tot;
       }' input
```

**Output**

```
bga 1
aab 1
bbb 2
aka 1
bga 1
abb 2
Total No - 8
```

Comment: You count `bga` twice separately?

Comment: @sudo_O, yes. OP wants to see them as different items if in different columns. I was displaying them separately but then merged into a single entry.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++{c[$1]++;c[$2]++}
       END{for(k in c){print k" - "c[k];s+=c[k]}print "\nTotal No -",s}' file
aka - 1
bga - 2
aab - 1
abb - 2
bbb - 2

Total No - 8
```

In the more readable script form:

```
!lines[$0]++{
    count[$1]++
    count[$2]++
}
END {
    for (line in count) {
        print line" - "count[line]
        sum += count[line]
    }
    print "\nTotal No -",sum
}
```

To run it in this form save it to a file `script.awk` and:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
aka - 1
bga - 2
aab - 1
abb - 2
bbb - 2

Total No - 8
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk '!b[$1,$3]++{a[$1]++} !c[$2,$3]++{a[$2]++} END{for (i in a) {print i,a[i];sum+=a[i]}print "Total -",sum}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit long command, but it's easy to understand:

```
gawk '{a[$3,$1,1];a[$3,$2,2]}END{for(i in a)print i}' input |
    cut -d $'\x1c' -f 2 | sort | uniq -c |
        awk -v OFS=' - ' '{sum+=$1;print $2,$1};END{print "\nTotal No",sum}'
```

---

```
aab - 1
abb - 2
aka - 1
bbb - 2
bga - 2

Total No - 8
```

Comment: Suggesting `gawk 'a[$3,$1,1];a[$3,$2,2];END{for(i in a)print i}'` could be very misleading as `a[$3,$1,1]` and `a[$3,$2,2]` are conditional without blocks, so if evaluated true the default block `{print $0}` would be executed but as no values are assigned to either arrays they default to false. Better to be explicit and use `gawk '{a[$3,$1,1];a[$3,$2,2]}END{for(i in a)print i}'` (only adds a single char) also `-vOFS` isn't portable accross all awks, throw in a space for safety `-v OFS` or explicitly use `gawk` like your first script.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ if (a[$1][$3] != 1){
    a[$1][$3] = 1; 
    total[$1]++; 
    }
if (a[$2][$3] != 1){
    a[$2][$3] = 1; 
    total[$2]++; 
    }
}
END {
    for (item in total){
        print item, total[item];
        totalCount += total[item];
    }
    print "\nTotal no - ", totalCount;
}
```

Output:

```
aka 1
bga 1
aab 1
abb 2
bbb 2

Total no -  7
```